# Different result from script ran at Startup

Tags: linux, install4j

I want to detect if certain libraries are installed on the computer before going forward with the install but I can't get it working properly.

I have the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

verify_distro(){
CHECK_IF_PACKAGE=`dpkg -s ia32-libs`
result=`echo $?`
echo ${result}
if [ ${result} == 0 ]; then
    echo "ia32-libs installed"
    return 0
else
    echo "not installed"
    return 1
fi
}

verify_distro
```

If I have ia32-libs installed and run it by hand in the console and then do an `echo $?` to see the output I get the 0 exit code as everything is installed correctly.

I have this script set to run at the startup phase of install, right after the Request privileges step, and have it set to wait for termination and output streams. In order for me to be able to stop the installer I also have the Failure Strategy set as "As user whether to retry or quit on failure".

The problem is that, despite having the package installed, the script still fails and the installer asks whether to continue or quit.

I'm not sure how to fix this problem so I can stop the installer if certain pre-requisites are not met. Or is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: So is there a discrepancy of the return value whether you run it manually or from the installer? Have you checked the logged return value in the .install4/installation.log? Also, you might redirect output of the "Run executable" action to the log file to check whether the script is executed correctly.

Comment: @IngoKegel, the problem stems from the fact that the script can't be run in the start-up phase, before it was copied to the installed directory.

If I run the script after the Register Add/Remove item phase for example (or wherever after the Install files phase) it runs correctly.

Is there any way to have a script run **before** the layout files are copied? I would like to have it run as a first step when starting the installer for example, so that the user will be warned of missing dependencies immediately, and not at the end of the install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the script file to Installer->Custom Code & Resource, then specify

```
${installer:sys.resourceDir}/scriptName.sh
```

for the "Executable" property or the "Run executable or batch file" action.

This will work in the "Startup" node as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to eliminate useless rows of code checking for other scripts output:

```
#!/bin/bash

verify_distro(){

    dpkg -s ia32-libs > /dev/null

    if [ $? == 0 ]; then
        echo "ia32-libs installed"
        return 0
    else
        echo "not installed"
        return 1
    fi

}

verify_distro
```

Comment: Unfortunately that has the same issue; despite the libraries being triggered I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say exactly what the error is when running this script at startup. It may be that your shell's PATH is not yet initialized, in which case the script will not be able to find the "dpkg" executable. If in fact that is the problem, specifying the full path to dpkg, e.g. "/usr/bin/dpkg  -s ia32-libs" would fix the issue.

Comment: The problem was with the script not being executed. See my comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157506/different-result-from-script-ran-at-startup#comment21425234_15157506).